# There is no way to vertically align plain text in div along with text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, ag-grid, text-alignment

I'm working with ag-grid and faced issue when I can't vertically align plain text in `div` along with `text-overflow: ellipsis`.
There is an option to use flexbox `align-items: center` but in that case you need to add one more DOM element. (https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text) which is not applicable in my case because I don't wan't to use `cellRendererFramework` on every cell.

Is it possible to do that without adding more DOM elements into parent `div`?

Here is demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXjebq

Comment: In your specific example, a `line-height: 100px` (i.e. the height of the div) should do the trick. Of course that requires knowing the div's height...

Answer (score 1):

> **Solution 1 - With Parent Container**

You actually have to add parent container and apply `display: flex; align-items: center` on it. Try the below code snippet it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, esse!</div>
</div>
```

> **Solution 2 - Without Parent Container**

You can also achieve by just adding `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; max-width: 100px;`. Try the below code snippet it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, esse!</div>
```

Comment: I know about this, but i asked about solution without adding more DOM element into parent div.

Comment: @ikurc i just update the above code snippet, please review it. Thanks